# how to change the value of the combo box when a textbox value is changed?

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that has one column with combo boxes populated with information, next to it are cells which show the item id when the item in the combo box is selected. What I need to be able to do is to search the item in reverse when I enter the item id to auto fill the combo box. So far I have a vlookup function in the cell to show the item id when the item is selected from the combo box.